# store string to array using tags in PHP

Tags: php, string

Need help. How to split string to array using tags ?

input:

```
<aa> test1 </aa> test2 <aa> test3 </aa> test4 ....
```

output:

```
arr[0] = <aa> test1 </aa>;
arr[1] = test2;
arr[2] = <aa> test3 </aa>;
arr[3] = test4;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [DOMNode::childNodes](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes)

Answer (score 4):

Using the super-awesome power of semi-dodgy regex!

```
$string = "<aa> test1 </aa> test2 <aa> test3 </aa> test4";
$arr = preg_split('/(<[0-9a-zA-Z_]+>[^<]*<\/[0-9a-zA-Z_]+>)/', $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: how can i set the pattern to fix {aa} and {/aa}? :D thank!

Comment: /({aa+}[^{]*{\/aa+})/ what if... <aa>asasd</aa>sdsds<aa>sdasd</aa>ss<sd>sda<sdsdsd>sad<

Comment: Don't type in the "aa" or "sd" or whatever. The original example allows any tag/element starting & ending with `<` and `>` with any combination of alphanumeric characters and underscores. If you want to check for braces ({}) instead of angle brackets (<>), just change the brackets and nothing else in the regex expression.

Comment: So... are you only ever checking for 1 specific element/tag - `<aa>`?

Comment: yes, tried this one in this site (http://php.fnlist.com/regexp/preg_split) "{aa} test {/aa} test sasdas{asd} {aa} test {/aa} test" with "/({aa}[^<]*{\/aa})/" and PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE; got only array[0] and array[1]...array (
  0 => '{aa} test {/aa} test sasdas{asd} {aa} test {/aa}',
  1 => ' test',
);

Comment: You just missed one of the angle brackets, that's all: `/({[0-9a-zA-Z_]+}[^{]*{\/[0-9a-zA-Z_]+})/`

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

I answered this earlier but It got down voted because some-one thought it wouldn't be possible to do it that way, well, it is possible. You just have to construct your own array, but first things first.

First of all, we have this string you mentioned:

```
$string = "<aa> test1 </aa> test2 <aa> test3 </aa> test4";
```

Now we can explode it:

```
$e = explode(' ', $string);
```

And we have an array $e which holds all the splits, can can get the results like this:

```
echo $e[0]. $e[1]. $e[2]. "<br>";
echo $e[3]. "<br>";
echo $e[4]. $e[5]. $e[6]. "<br>";
echo $e[7]. "<br>";
```

The output is:

```
<aa> test1 </aa>;
test2;
<aa> test3 </aa>;
test4;
```

But this is quite messy, understandable. However, can walk through the array and construct a single array like you wanted:

```
$result = array();
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($e) ; $i++)
{
    if($i % 2 == 0)
    {
        $tempRes = $e[$i]. $e[$i+1]. $e[$i+2];
    }
    else
    {
        $tempRes = $e[$i+2];
        $i+=2;
    }
    array_push($result, $tempRes);
}
```

The output is the same.

This may not be the BEST approach, but it works.

Comment: I understand that this can be done using preg_split, but why does it deserve to be down voted?